# Fuse-box - Setting project for JQuery, Bootstrap and ionicons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ionicons, fusebox

I'm trying to set a Fuse-box environment to be able to bundle JQuery, Boostrap and ionicons packages into two files:

- static/assets/js/bundle.js
- static/assets/css/bundle.css

I have two problems:

1. My JQuery script doesn't work.
2. CSSResourcePlugin generates no resource files, so ionicons aren't shown.

My fuse.js file is set as follows:

```js
const fuse = FuseBox.init({
    homeDir: 'src/',
    output: 'static/$name.js',
    plugins: [
        [
            SassPlugin({ importer: true }),
            CSSResourcePlugin({
                dist: 'static/assets/resources',
                resolve: f => `assets/resources/${f}`
            }),
            CSSPlugin({
                group: 'bundle.css',
                outFile: `static/assets/css/bundle.css`
            })
        ]
    ],
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            source: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            exports: 'jQuery'
        }
    }
});

fuse.dev({ httpServer: true, hmr: true, port: 3000 });
fuse.bundle('assets/js/bundle').instructions('>index.ts').watch().hmr();
fuse.run();
```

My typescript files:

index.ts

```js
import 'tether';
import 'bootstrap';
import './ts/sliders';

import './app.scss';
```

./ts/sliders.ts

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'slick-carousel';

$(function() {
    console.log('dede');
});
```

My app.scss file:

```js
@import './scss/custom.scss';

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons.scss';
@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss';
@import '~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';
```

The whole project is available on Github:
https://github.com/jezikk/fuse-box-test

Can you please help me with settings?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that resource files reachable (sometimes they are not)
It's easier if you import the actual `dist` from bootstrap.